# no overloaded function takes X arguments

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to add another operator to this class.

It already had the operator:

```
void operator()(model& m, output_container& out, const precalculate& p, const igrid& ig, const precalculate& p_widened, const igrid& ig_widened, const vec& corner1, const vec& corner2, incrementable* increment_me, rng& generator) const;
```

I just want to remove the "incrementable* increment_me" part. So I removed it from the calls and the code itself. For some reason it is giving the below error.

Error:

```
Error   2   error C2661: 'monte_carlo::monte_carlo' : no overloaded function takes 9 arguments  C:\vina_code\vinaSingleThread\src\main\main.cpp 226 1   vinaSingleThread
```

The new call in header:

```
void operator()(model& m, output_container& out, const precalculate& p, const igrid& ig, const precalculate& p_widened, const igrid& ig_widened, const vec& corner1, const vec& corner2, rng& generator) const;
```

The new call in cpp:

```
void monte_carlo::operator()(model& m, output_container& out, const precalculate& p, const igrid& ig, const precalculate& p_widened, const igrid& ig_widened, const vec& corner1, const vec& corner2, rng& generator) const
{
    vec authentic_v(1000, 1000, 1000); // FIXME? this is here to avoid max_fl/max_fl
    conf_size s = m.get_size();
    change g(s);
    output_type tmp(s, 0);
    tmp.c.randomize(corner1, corner2, generator);
    fl best_e = max_fl;
    quasi_newton quasi_newton_par; quasi_newton_par.max_steps = ssd_par.evals;

    VINA_U_FOR(step, num_steps)
    {
        output_type candidate = tmp;
        mutate_conf(candidate.c, m, mutation_amplitude, generator);
        quasi_newton_par(m, p, ig, candidate, g, hunt_cap);
        if(step == 0 || metropolis_accept(tmp.e, candidate.e, temperature, generator))
        {
            tmp = candidate;

            m.set(tmp.c); // FIXME? useless?

            // FIXME only for very promising ones
            if(tmp.e < best_e || out.size() < num_saved_mins)
            {
                quasi_newton_par(m, p, ig, tmp, g, authentic_v);
                m.set(tmp.c); // FIXME? useless?
                tmp.coords = m.get_heavy_atom_movable_coords();
                add_to_output_container(out, tmp, min_rmsd, num_saved_mins); // 20 - max size
                if(tmp.e < best_e)
                    best_e = tmp.e;
            }
        }
    }
    VINA_CHECK(!out.empty());
    VINA_CHECK(out.front().e <= out.back().e); // make sure the sorting worked in the correct order

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!!

EDIT (sorry about that, should have added this):

main call (line 226):

```
monte_carlo mc(m, out_cont, prec, ig, prec_widened, ig_widened, corner1, corner2, generator);
```

Here are the full files:

monet_carlo.cpp: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wM3uVqKt

monte_carlo.h: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WV1fSbmv

main: too large to include, look at main call.

Comment: Post the actual code that gives the error, presumably in `main.cpp`  line 226.

Comment: Please provide more details like the code in `main.cpp` or specify what compiler are you using and how do you invoke it, so we can help you more specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original header has 10 arguments, the new header 9.

You are evidently using 9 arguments in the function call in `C:\vina_code\vinaSingleThread\src\main\main.cpp 226 1` assuming from the error message.

However, the compiler seems to use the original declaration of `monte_carlo::operator()`, so it still requires 10 arguments.

Make sure you are using your updated monte_carlo source and header.

**UPDATE after providing more code**

The line from main.cpp:226 attempts to construct an object `mc` of class `monte_carlo` while the constructor has no arguments. You cannot use `operator()` (just like any other method) until you create the object. Try changing it to the following:

```
monte_carlo mc;
// Now the object is created and we can use its methods, for example operator().
mc(m, out_cont, prec, ig, prec_widened, ig_widened, corner1, corner2, generator);
```

By the way, you are passing a lot of constant values to member variables in the constructor initializer list. I would make them `static const` class members (if they are fixed for all instances) or default parameters.

Comment: Can I have two operators, one with 9 args, another with 10?

Comment: You can. I assumed you are replacing the original one. So are you adding another one? Is the added method `operator()` with 9 arguments mentioned in the original class declaration?

Comment: I believe so. Look at the edit I made included the .cpp and .h file. Thank you!

Comment: Silly me, it's been a while...that did it, thank you!